# Unit testing a .NET Standard 1.6 library

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xunit.net, project.json

I am having trouble finding up to date documentation on how to unit test a .NET Standard 1.6 class library (which can be referenced from a .NET Core project).

Here is what my `project.json` looks like for my library:

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Portable.BouncyCastle": "1.8.1.2"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {}
  }
}
```

Now the left over task is to be able to create some sort of a project that can do the unit testing.  The goal is to use xUnit since it seems that this is what the .NET Core team is pushing.

I went ahead and created another .NET Portable library project that has a project.json that looks like this:

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta4-build3444",
    "xunit.runner.visualstudio": "2.1.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {

    }
  }
}
```

My test class within that project looks like this:

```
using USB.EnterpriseAutomation.Security.DotNetCore;
using Xunit;

namespace Security.DotNetCore.Test
{
    public class AesEncryptionHelperTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void AesEncryptDecrypt()
        {
            var input = "Hello world!";
            var encrypted = AesEncryptionHelper.AesEncrypt(input);
            var decrypted = AesEncryptionHelper.AesDecrypt(encrypted);

            Assert.Equal(input, decrypted);
        }
    }
}
```

When I go ahead and build that project, the Test Explorer is not seeing any of my tests.

How do I go about creating a unit test that's able to test this library?

Comment: Has anyone figured this out in VS 2017 RTM?  When I am trying to test a NetStandard library my tests can't be found.  I am referencing version 2.2 of xunit and xunit.runner.visualstudio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I currently have a working project using xunit 2.1.0 and dotnet-test-xunit 2.2.0-preview2-build1029.

This is my `project.json` for the unit test project:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "MyProject.Library": {
      "target": "project",
    },
    "xunit": "2.1.0"
  },
  "description": "Unit tests",
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dotnet"
    }
  },
  "testRunner": "xunit"
}
```

This works both on the command line (via `dotnet test`) and in the Visual Studio 2015 Test Explorer.

I think that `dotnet-test-xunit` is being deprecated, but I'm not sure. All of the above will likely change after project.json goes away, but this works today.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 RC does require a different setup, which I tried yesterday.

Comment: @LexLi Good to know. I'm sure I'll have to figure all this out again when I upgrade. :)

Comment: I attached the info here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/preview3/tools/dotnet-test This link (for SDK preview 3) won't work forever, but Microsoft should have an updated version always at https://learn.microsoft.com somewhere in the future.

Answer (score 9):

I found the issue posted on xUnit's GitHub page here: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1032

As Brad Wilson explains, NETStandard libraries must be tested with either a dotnet core library or a full .Net Framework library.

In my case I made my unit test library a full "classic desktop" library and Test Explorer was able to run my tests.