# Xamarin portable .NETStandard 1.5 unit test

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, portability, .net-standard-1.5

I created a portable class library [image: Project selection for portable] and then targeted it at .NETStandard 1.5 from the project properties[image]. I then created a second project with the exact same project settings, but added code to use for invoking and testing the code in the first project. But I have been unable to add MSTest to use for triggering execution. I tried using the guidance at [stack overflow # 41350323](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350323/unit-testing-a-net-standard-1-6-library)
but ran into problems. Wondering if anyone out there has been able to use MSTest for unit testing portable .NETStandard class libraries. Note that I also tried using the guidance for [.NET core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/05/30/announcing-mstest-framework-support-for-net-core-rc2-asp-net-core-rc2/) but the MSTest framework nuget does not seem to support .NETStandard.

If not a unit test, then is there a way to invoke from a console? I just need to test my code and this should not be so difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define logic in a .NET Standard project (don't use PCL though, use the .NET Standard Class Library template in VS2017 RC), but then the unit test project should have its target platform (UWP/Desktop/Xamarin or others) instead of .NET Standard. For example, in VS2017 RC, a typical unit testing project can be a .NET Core console app.