# Using MSTest Framework for testing applications targeting .NET Standard 1.6 and higher

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest, .net-core, .net-standard

I'm migrating [my project](https://github.com/oleh-zheleznyak/IntroductionToAlgorithms/pull/1) from .NETFramework 4.5.1 to .NET Standard 1.6

The project is using MSTest framework, and I would like to keep it that way for now and avoid rewriting tests in another framework (XUnit, NUnit or the like)

Currently, [MSTest framework support was announced for .NET Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/05/30/announcing-mstest-framework-support-for-net-core-rc2-asp-net-core-rc2/) only, and, quite naturally the `dotnet-test-mstest 1.1.2-preview` [package available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-test-mstest/1.1.2-preview) does not support .NET Standard, so I cannot have my test projects target .NET Standard

However, according to [compatibility matrix](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/), .NET Standard 1.6 is compatible with .NET Core 1.0.
So I have my test assemblies targeting .NET Core 1.0 and referencing my system-under-test assemblies that target .NET Standard 1.6 - and it works just fine.

**The question is - is this a good decision going forward?**

I have not found any road map for MSTest, and I'm wondering whether this trick will still work when I migrate to .NET Standard 2.0 ?
Should I change my test framework to something else, that has more up to date support, for example XUnit?

Even Microsoft [documentation points to XUnit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test), are they abandoning MSTest?

Please note that this [is not a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41486116/xamarin-portable-netstandard-1-5-unit-test), since my question is about the perspective for the future, not only current state of affairs.

Comment: Guys, any feedback is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**>> The project is using MSTest framework, and I would like to keep it that way for now and avoid rewriting tests in another framework (XUnit, NUnit or te like)**

Sounds reasonable.

**>> I cannot have my test projects target .NET Standard**

You can.

Please see this post for reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/11/29/evolving-the-test-platform-part-3-net-core-convergence-and-cross-plat/
Do note that you no longer need the dotnet-test-mstest package. Use MSTest.TestAdapter instead.

**>> Even Microsoft documentation points to XUnit**

In this case, yes. But then there are other projects that use MSTest heavily as well.

We work on both the MSTest test framework and the VS Test platform. As a Test Platform, we take a pluralistic approach and would like to leave the choice of test framework to the developer (as opposed to taking sides in favour of any one framework). You can read more about this approach here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/07/25/evolving-the-visual-studio-test-platform-part-1/.

**>> are they abandoning MSTest?**

Not at all.

Please see  here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/01/20/open-sourcing-the-vs-test-platform/, and here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/13399980-make-ms-test-framework-opensouce to get a glimpse of the road ahead. We will announce more – specifically in terms of a roadmap – soon.

**>> The question is - is this a good decision going forward?**

Yes (based on all of the above).

Comment: thanks for the answer, please allow me to digest all the provided info before I mark this as an answer!

Comment: Of course. Let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: MSTest++ easy to use, integrates with visual studio, nothing external needed. just works!